# Raising event from method in threadpool

Tags: c#, events, threadpool

The following code queues a method on the thread pool. The method is supposed to raise a couple of events, but these aren't getting raised (or they are being raised, but aren't getting subscribed in the right context?).

Note that the `TeamMember` class inherits from `AsyncFiller` which is an abstract class where the `OnProgressing` and `OnComplete` events are implemented.

I'm not surprised that this code isn't working, but I can't quite figure out how to get the events to fire.

I've searched this site, google, and MSDN for info on the threadpool and events, but just haven't been able to put it together in my head.

Can you explain why this isn't working, and what I'm doing wrong?

**The Code**

```
public class TeamMember : AsyncFiller, ITeamMember 
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string ServiceCardNumber { get; private set; }
    public DateTime CurrentDateTime { get; private set; }
    public string CurrentStore { get; private set; }
    public IWorkDay WorkDay { get; private set; }

    public void GetTeamMemberInfoAsync(String serviceCardNumber, DateTime dateWorked, IBusinessLogicFactory businessLogicFactory) {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( state => GetTeamMemberInfo(serviceCardNumber, dateWorked, businessLogicFactory));
    }

    private void GetTeamMemberInfo(String serviceCardNumber, DateTime dateWorked, IBusinessLogicFactory businessLogicFactory)
    {
        var tmdm = businessLogicFactory.DataAccessFactory.CreateTeamMemberDataManager();
        var tmd = tmdm.GetTeamMemberData(serviceCardNumber);
        Name = tmd.TeamMemberName;
        ServiceCardNumber = serviceCardNumber;
        CurrentDateTime = Time.SystemTime.Now();
        CurrentStore = tmd.CurrentStore;
        OnProgressing(new ReportingProgressEventArgs("Team member information is complete."));
        OnComplete(new TeamMemberCompleteEventArgs(this));
    }
}
```

**Sample of a Failing Test**
(both the progress and completion event ordinals are zero, which tells me either the event isn't being raised, or is not being subscribed to in the correct context)

```
[TestFixture]
public class TeamMemberSpecs
{
    [SetUp]
    public void TestSetup() {
        AuditEngine.Time.SystemTime.ResetDateTime();
    }

    [Test]
    public void GetTeamMemberInfoAsync_UponCompletion_RaisesProgressThenCompleteEvent() {
        var blf = Substitute.For<IBusinessLogicFactory>();
        var serviceCardNumber = "12345";
        var dateWorked = new DateTime(2014, 10, 24);
        var tm = new TeamMember();

        var eventOrder = 0;
        var progressEventOrdinal = 0;
        var completionEventOrdinal = 0;
        tm.ReportingProgress += (o, e) => progressEventOrdinal = ++eventOrder;
        tm.Complete += (o, e) => completionEventOrdinal = ++eventOrder;
        tm.GetTeamMemberInfoAsync(serviceCardNumber,dateWorked,blf);

        Assert.AreEqual(1,progressEventOrdinal,"Progress event order was incorrect.");
        Assert.AreEqual(2,completionEventOrdinal,"Completion event order was incorrect.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Trying to assert if an event handler ran *before* it could possibly ever run is not going to work.  Always avoid fire-and-forget threading.

Comment: To clarify, are you saying that my code might be working, but my test approach is likely the problem?

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Do you have a recommendation for how I could restructure the test to avoid that issue?

Comment: Full disclosure, I'm not really familiar with what you mean by "fire and forget" (not in this context anyway)